# Wrong Qt path with QtCreator, cmake, and a static compilation from Qt 5.2.0

Tags: qt, path, cmake, static-libraries, qt-creator

The path to the static Qt library is wrongly setup by cmake under QtCreator (windows):

it should be C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\msvc2012-static_64\qtbase
instead it get configured to D:\GitHub\MyProject where the project lives.

So linking fails.

Here is what i checked so far:

- The QTDIR environnement var is correctly set by QtCreator to C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\msvc2012-static_64\qtbase
- The project works well with a dynamic version of Qt 5.1.1, both with QtCreator 2.8 and 3.0

For what i understand, the cmake command `find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)` is responsible for finding and including the Qt modules.

Here is the corresponding part of CmakeCache.txt:

```
    //The directory containing a CMake configuration file for Qt5Core.
    Qt5Core_DIR:PATH=C:/Qt/Qt5.2.0/msvc2012-static_64/qtbase/lib/cmake/Qt5Core

    //The directory containing a CMake configuration file for Qt5Gui.
    Qt5Gui_DIR:PATH=C:/Qt/Qt5.2.0/msvc2012-static_64/qtbase/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui

    //The directory containing a CMake configuration file for Qt5Multimedia.
    Qt5Multimedia_DIR:PATH=C:/Qt/Qt5.2.0/msvc2012-static_64/qtbase/lib/cmake/Qt5Multimedia

    //The directory containing a CMake configuration file for Qt5Network.
    Qt5Network_DIR:PATH=C:/Qt/Qt5.2.0/msvc2012-static_64/qtbase/lib/cmake/Qt5Network

    //The directory containing a CMake configuration file for Qt5Widgets.
    Qt5Widgets_DIR:PATH=C:/Qt/Qt5.2.0/msvc2012-static_64/qtbase/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets
```

Here is what's shown in QtCreator (v3.0.0):

[image: Here is what's shown in QtCreator (v3.0.0)]

The missing icons indicate that the file has not been found by QtCreator.
When i right click on one of them and click on "Show in Explorer", it opens the explorer in "Computer"(where you see all your drives) so not on the right place !

I already spent a few days on the problem, any idea is welcome :)